# Transforming a data of key value pairs to label and key

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have the following data

```
const data = [
  {
    _id: "John Doe",
    cashShare: 2,
    stockShare: 3000,
  },
  {
    _id: "Jane Doe",
    cashShare: 0,
    stockShare: 20,
  },
  {
    _id: "Jack Doe",
    cashShare: 311,
    stockShare: 1311,
  },
];
```

I want to transform it into:

```
[
  { _id: 'John Doe', label: 'Cash Share', value: 2 },
  { _id: 'Jane Doe', label: 'Cash Share', value: 0 },
  { _id: 'Jack Doe', label: 'Cash Share', value: 311 },
  { _id: 'John Doe', label: 'Stock Share', value: 3000 },
  { _id: 'Jane Doe', label: 'Stock Share', value: 20 },
  { _id: 'Jack Doe', label: 'Stock Share', value: 1311 }
]
```

So I did this:

```
const cashShare = data.map(({ _id, cashShare, stockShare }) => {
  return {
    _id,
    label: "Cash Share",
    value: cashShare,
  };
});

const stockShare = data.map(({ _id, cashShare, stockShare }) => {
  return {
    _id,
    label: "Stock Share",
    value: stockShare,
  };
});

const mergedData = [...cashShare, ...stockShare];
console.log(mergedData);
```

I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this because I feel like this is unnecessary long, but it is clear what I am doing.

Answer (score 2):

You could map each object to a list of objects (one for each label), and then use [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to turn the nested array into a flat array. If you care about ordering, you could then sort by label to put all the `Cash Share`s first.

```js
const data = [
  {
    _id: "John Doe",
    cashShare: 2,
    stockShare: 3000,
  },
  {
    _id: "Jane Doe",
    cashShare: 0,
    stockShare: 20,
  },
  {
    _id: "Jack Doe",
    cashShare: 311,
    stockShare: 1311,
  },
];

const mergedData = data.map(({ _id, cashShare, stockShare }) => [
  {
    _id,
    label: "Cash Share",
    value: cashShare,
  },
  {
    _id,
    label: "Stock Share",
    value: stockShare,
  }
]).flat()
.sort((lhs, rhs) => lhs.label < rhs.label ? -1 : 1); // sort is only necessary if you care about order
console.log(mergedData);
```

I'm not sure how the performance of this option compares to yours. I've assumed you're mostly thinking about readability rather than efficiently processing large datasets.

Answer (score 2):

A short review;

- You process the list twice, ideally you process the list only once

  - You can run 1 function once per object with `map` and then `flat`
  - You could even run `flatMap` which is faster than running `map` and `flat` separately
- The code for `cashShare` and `stockShare` is violating [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) I would use a function called `getLabelValue that looks like this

  ```
    function getLabelValue(o, label){
      return {
        _id: o._id,
        label,
        value: o[label]
      }
    }
  ```